# Can't save image for barcode generation in ASP.NET C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to save an image using System.Drawing.Save() and I keep getting a Invalid Parameter exception.

Can somebody please take a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code that generates the barcode image.

```
 public class BarcodeHelper
    {
        Font barcodeFont;
        public BarcodeHelper()
        {
             PrivateFontCollection fonts;
             FontFamily family = LoadFontFamily("~/../fonts/Code128bWin.ttf", out fonts);   
             barcodeFont = new Font(family, 20.0f);   

            // when done:   
            barcodeFont.Dispose();   
            family.Dispose();   
            family.Dispose();
        }
        public FontFamily LoadFontFamily(string fileName, out PrivateFontCollection fontCollection) 
        { 
            fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection(); 
            fontCollection.AddFontFile(fileName); 
            return fontCollection.Families[0]; 
        }

        public Image GenerateBarcode(string barcodeText) 
        {
            Image barcodeImage;
            using (barcodeImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\YodelShipping\YodelShipping\images\barcode.bmp"))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(barcodeImage))
                {
                    g.DrawString(barcodeText,
                        new Font(barcodeFont, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 
                        barcodeImage.Height /2, barcodeImage.Width / 2);
                }
            }
            return barcodeImage;
        }
    }
```

Here is where I call the code to create and save the barcode image. I'm getting the exception, when calling the Save() method.

```
System.Drawing.Image img = barcodeHelper.GenerateBarcode("2lgbub51aj+01000002");
img.Save("~/images/barcode.png");
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Barcode barcode = new Barcode();
        BarcodeLib.TYPE type = BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE93;
        BarcodeLib.SaveTypes y = SaveTypes.JPG;
        barcode.Encode(type, "12344");

        barcode.SaveImage(Server.MapPath("~/Barcode\\abc.jpg"), y);
                    Label1.Text = "Image Saved successfully";

    }
    catch (Exception EE)
    {
        EE.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your file path ("~/images/barcode.png"). You need to use a valid absolute path (e.g. "c:/projects/myproject/images/barcode.png").

**Edit:** I just noticed this is ASP.NET, so you should only need to do this:

```
img.Save(Server.MapPath("~/images/barcode.png"));
```

Note that you will probably run into permissions issues at some point (the account running your ASP.NET app will need write permissions at this location).

Comment: Just tried that and I'm still getting the exception. Any ideas?

Comment: No, I'm kinda stumped here. The docs say "Saving the image to the same file it was constructed from is not allowed and throws an exception.", but it looks like your original is `barcode.bmp` and not `barcode.png`, so it should work. Try saving in a different absolute location, and save it as `barcode.bmp` (in case it for some reason can't encode to a PNG).

Comment: You may also want to user the overload of `Save` that takes an image format (since you're converting from BMP to PNG), like this:  `img.Save(Server.MapPath("~/images/barcode.png"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.PNG);`

Answer (score 0):

1. Install ProcMon (free from Microsoft)
2. Run it and create a filter for Path contains barcode.png
3. Run your code.

It logs every file system call and the result (with detailed information)

Some ideas

1. The directory doesn't exist
2. You don't have permission

Answer (score 0):

The `Image.Save` method needs the full path. The tilde (~) only works within ASP.Net. Try:

```
img.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/barcode.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the fact that you're trying to save to a relative path. Trying using an absolute path, or getting the current path via a call to Environment.CurrentDirectory, and prepending that to your barcode.png path.

Answer (score 0):

I would check that a) the images folder exists where you think it does, and b) that your ASP.NET process has the rights to write to it.